# PASAR DATOS JSON DE UNA TABLA A OTRA EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json, base-de-datos

Hola quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con este inconveniente que tengo.
En una columna de una tabla en `Mysql` se guarda una lista `JSON` como esta:

```
    {
  "Sender": "chevrolet=gminfoleads.com@mg.gminfoleads.com",
  "X-Mailgun-Sending-Ip": "198.61.254.10",
  "X-Mailgun-Sid": "WyI5MTY2ZiIsICJmYXVzdG9fY2FyY2hpQGhvdG1haWwuaXQiLCAiMGQ3OWM4Il0=",
  "List-Unsubscribe": "<mailto:u+mq6tazbxhfrtqjtjhvsdgojugu3dinzvmy2gknbxgnstmzddhe4wcojxgazdeyzqg44wmjjugbzxo2lgoqxgozlomvzgc5dfmqtgqplemu3donjrha2wmzjqgy2tmzjtmvrtgmruha2dsyjzhe4dgobxmuthepkgmf2xg5dpl5rwc4tdnbusknbqnbxxi3lbnfwc42luez2d2jjsie@mg.gminfoleads.com>",
  "Received": "from [127.0.0.1] (server.provendatarecovery.com [144.208.68.130]) by mxa.mailgun.org with ESMTP id 595e7aa5.7f65c8243c30-smtp-out-n01; Thu, 06 Jul 2017 18:00:05 -0000 (UTC)",
  "Message-Id": "<d39456475f4e473e6dc99a97022c079f@swift.generated>",
  "Date": "Thu, 06 Jul 2017 13:00:04 -0500",
  "Subject": "Est\u00e1s un paso m\u00e1s cerca de tu nuevo auto",
  "From": "Chevrolet Ecuador <chevrolet@gminfoleads.com>",
  "To": "Fausto_carchi@hotmail.it",
  "Mime-Version": "1.0",
  "Content-Type": [
    "text\/html",
    {
      "charset": "utf-8"
    }
  ],
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding": [
    "quoted-printable",
    {}
  ]
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es como pasar los datos a otra tabla donde tenga cada uno de los campos de la lista `JSON` por separado mediante el uso de`tiggers`.

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: usas otro lenguaje para insertarlo a la tabla?, o solo usas el mysql?, quieres pasar ese json a otra columna de otra tabla?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez no solo quiero saber mediante mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER insert_jason
AFTER INSERT
   ON tabla1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tabla2( columnajson)VALUES(NEW.columnaJson);
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Lo que hace este código es que cada vez que insertes algo en la `tabla1` se ejecutara un insert en la `tabla2`, entonces la tabla2 tiene que tener el mismo campo que la tabla 1 para poder hacer el insert(esto hay que verificarlo), posteriormente el `values(NEW.columnajson)` tomara el valor del campo que se inserto en la tabla1. Creo que ese sería un ejemplo con la informacion que me diste.